# TinyMCE editor to MPDF page content limit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tinymce, mpdf

I have a site which uses Tiny MCE to allow users to input content in a page layout. Sort of like Microsoft Word but the pages are tabbed. 
When the user is happy with their content they can publish it as a PDF using MPDF.

The problem I'm facing is that if a user enters too much text or images into a "page" tab, the PDF will produce 2 pages for that page.

What I'd like to do is somehow detect if this was going to happen and either restrict the user or at least show an error.

I'm guessing maybe there is some way to tell before publishing, whether it will render as 1 page or 2? Maybe it could ajax when the content is changed and do some sort of MPDF check? Would this be a good way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

In mPDF, there is no way of telling the number of pages resulting document will have until `Output()` method is called.

You could do something like this:

```
$string = $mpdf->Output('', 'S');
if (count($mpdf->pages) > 1) {
    // Display error
} else {
    // return PDF from $string variable containing PDF contents
    // or call plain $mpdf->Output() which will also handle correct content-type headers
}
```